# PHP Change image automatically in every 2 hours

Tags: php

i need a code for PHP changing image in every 2 hours at a time. Actually i have 6 images and i want to change these images automatically in every 2 hours. how can i achieve this anyone helps really appreciated.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Where is shown your image? HTML?

Comment: What you need is javascript

Comment: How do you want to show them?

Comment: i have show image in same php page

Comment: Have you written any code?

Comment: no i have  no code

Answer (score 2):

If you have 6 images, for example

```
$img1 = '/image1.png';
$img2 = '/image2.png';
$img3 = '/image3.png';
$img4 = '/image4.png';
$img5 = '/image5.png';
$img6 = '/image6.png';
```

You can go making a if commands which would be most simple solution

```
if(date('g') == 1 || date('g') == 2){
    $image = $img1;
}
if(date('g') == 3 || date('g') == 4){
    $image = $img2;
}
if(date('g') == 5 || date('g') == 6){
    $image = $img3;
}

...
```

Maybe not most effective code but should work like a quick solution

`date('g')` is returning 12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros and it should be current time. You could also do something like this `date('g', strtotime('now'))` but I don't think you need to

Comment: I personally like this idea and is the absolute simplest solution to this problem. It's not the best code but works as intended and is simple to understand.

Comment: Short but helpful

Answer (score 0):

in php this could be acheived in a few simple lines of code, In fact, I put together a simple example that prints a different image based on what time it is - you should be easily able to adapt this to output a different image every hour.

```
$i = substr(time(), -1, 2 );     


switch ($i) {     

case 0: 
        $img = '<img src="zero.JPG" alt="img">'; 
        break; 
case 1: 
        $img = '<img src="one.JPG" alt="img">'; 
        break; 
case 2: 
        $img = '<img src="two.JPG" alt="img">'; 
        break; 
case 3: 
        $img = '<img src="three.JPG" alt="img">'; 
        break; 
case 4: 
        $img = '<img src="four.JPG" alt="img">'; 
        break; 
case 5: 
        $img = '<img src="five.JPG" alt="img">'; 
        break; 
case 6: 
        $img = '<img src="six.JPG" alt="img">'; 
        break; 
case 7: 
        $img = '<img src="seven.JPG" alt="img">'; 
        break; 
case 8: 
        $img = '<img src="eight.JPG" alt="img">'; 
        break; 
case 9: 
        $img = '<img src="nine.JPG" alt="img">'; 
        break; 
} 

echo $img;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
var i = 0; var path = new Array(); 

// LIST OF IMAGES 
path[0] = "image.jpg"; 
path[1] = "image1.jpg"; 
path[2] = "image2.jpg"; 
path[3] = "image3.jpg";
path[4] = "image4.jpg";
path[5] = "image5.jpg";


function swapImage() 
  { 
document.slide.src = path[i]; 
if(i < path.length - 1) i++; 
else i = 0; 
setTimeout("swapImage()",7200000); 
  } 
window.addEventListener("load",  swapImage); 
</script> 
<img height="230" name="slide" src="image.jpg" width="200" /></p>
</center></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    //add images acoordingly
    $imageArr = array('image1.png','image2.png');
    foreach($imageArr as $path){
        $im = imagecreatefrompng($path);
        imagepng($im);
        imagedestroy($im);
        sleep(2*60*60);
    }
?>
```

is it the code you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// change every X hours
define('EVERY', 2);

// here we have the images
$images = [
    'image1.png',
    'image2.png',
    'image3.png',
    'image4.png',
    'image5.png',
    'image6.png'
];

// anonymous function to get the current Image
$imageFor = function ($hour) use ($images) {
    $index = $hour / EVERY % count($images);
    return $images[$index];
};

// output for all the hours
for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++)
    echo "$i\t", $imageFor($i), PHP_EOL;

$currentHour = date('G');
echo "[$currentHour] Now showing Image: ", $imageFor($currentHour);
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
0   image1.png
1   image1.png
2   image2.png
3   image2.png
4   image3.png
5   image3.png
6   image4.png
7   image4.png
8   image5.png
9   image5.png
10  image6.png
11  image6.png
12  image1.png
13  image1.png
14  image2.png
15  image2.png
16  image3.png
17  image3.png
18  image4.png
19  image4.png
20  image5.png
21  image5.png
22  image6.png
23  image6.png
[8] Now showing Image: image5.png
```

[Play with me @ 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/H22n8)